# What is meant by public registry?

Tags: company-policy, certification, employment-agreement

I have been trying to fill the blanks in an agreement sent to me by a company and i am confused that what does public registry mean???
I have filled the rest except the blank after "public registry" in the following sections of agreement.
**Between XXXX S.A., a corporation registered under the laws of the Republic of country X in the

> Public Registry XXXX,

with the legal identification number XXX, with domicile in Country, City, address represented herein by Mr.XXX,  nationality XXX permanent resident card number XXX, as emerges accredited from "Certificate of Registration of Trade and Deputy" attached.**

Comment: I would guess that it is someplace that companies are registered with the government, but I'm just guessing. What country are you in?

Comment: Does it really matter because this agreement is of international company so this agreement is for every country.

Comment: Lets say its for your country...

Comment: Yes, it really does matter.  Depending on the laws of the location of the work, it would let someone with knowledge of that locale know what you're talking about.  In the U.S., you would be referred to the State Department of the state the work is to be done in.  This has a "European Feel" to it, by the phrasing, but knowing if it's EU or what else would really help get a good answer.

Comment: Its from Uruguay and for Afghanistan

Comment: I think in the end this question is going to be off-topic here. Your best bet is just to ask the people who sent you the contract in the first place.

Comment: I agree with David that it's off topic.  However I would suggest that when reviewing or attempting to understand a legal document it's best to consult an attorney.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just the official repository of businesses that have been incorporated in that country.

When a company is incorporated it fills out paperwork and enumerates the officers and other important corporate details.  The wording implies a single location but it could be distributed in hundreds of bureaucratic offices that each handle the different forms.  The files those forms get entered into would be the Public Registry.